# How to use Clang Static Analyzer on file save Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

The only way I've found out how to run Clang Static Analyzer in Qt Creator was by clicking on it in the menu. Is there a way to configure it so that it runs automatically when I save a file? If not, is there some way to lint the code upon file save with a plugin or something like that?